# RecyclerView with unknown/variable row layouts

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

Since RecyclerView uses ViewHolders, it means that you must have a predefined layout for each row. But what if each row needs to have a variable amount of views displayed?

For example, say I'm creating an instant messaging application where users can attach pictures to messages. They could attach anywhere from 0 to x pictures. When you create a RecyclerView to display these pictures (that are downloaded from a server), how would you make the rows include the correct number of ImageViews to display them?

There's a few ways I can think of doing this, but none really seem like good options.

1. Create ImageViews in onBindViewHolder, add them to a layout in the ViewHolder. (Isn't this what the ViewHolder tries to prevent? This would probably be laggy, especially with lots of pictures)
2. Restrict the amount of pictures the user can attach to a message to x, then add x ImageViews to the layout that are set to invisible/gone. In onBindViewHolder, set the ImageViews to display the picture and set these ImageViews visible. (What if I allow pictures & videos to be attached? Do I then need to add x ImageViews and x VideoViews as well?)
3. Put a GridView in each RecyclerView item and populate the GridView
   inside onBindViewHolder. (I assume this would have no benefit over
   option #1 because it's pretty much the same thing?)

That's all I can think of. Is there any other option that is designed for this sort of situation that I have not come across? Or what are the typical approaches taken towards this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a heterogenous `RecyclerView` which will display multiple different `ViewHolder`s.  There are several ways to accomplish this.

The basic approach is that based on the number of photos/videos associated with each item in your `RecyclerView.Adapter` you would override `getItemViewType(int position)` (a method which is part of the `RecyclerView.Adapter` class) to return a different `int`. This `int` is the `viewType` parameter passed into `createViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)`.  You would then use the correct `ViewHolder`/layout based on the `viewType` argument.

See [here](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Heterogenous-Layouts-inside-RecyclerView) for a good tutorial.

If you don't mind using a library for an alternate approach I recommend [AdapterDelegates](https://github.com/sockeqwe/AdapterDelegates).

Comment: I know about different view types in a RecyclerView but this isn't relevant to my problem. View types are for applying different layouts to rows, but it still assumes the rows have static layouts. I need a solution where the RecyclerView items have a variable amount of views within the layout.

Comment: I see.  Then I would go with your second proposed idea for doing this using one viewholder and showing/hiding based on the row content or I would still restrict the number of images and videos as in idea 2 but create separate viewholders representing the possible combinations.